# Count total of values in variable in JS for loop

Tags: javascript

I have a `for` loop in my script that loops through a set of `markerNodes` results. I was wondering, how easy is it to create a `total` variable that adds up the integer value in `amount` & outputs at the end?

```
for (var i = 0; i < markerNodes.length; i++) {
   var name = markerNodes[i].getAttribute("name");
   var address = markerNodes[i].getAttribute("address");
   var amount = markerNodes[i].getAttribute("amount");
   var distance = parseFloat(markerNodes[i].getAttribute("distance"));
   var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(
        parseFloat(markerNodes[i].getAttribute("lat")),
        parseFloat(markerNodes[i].getAttribute("lng")));
   createOption(name, distance, i);
   createMarker(latlng, name, address, total);
   bounds.extend(latlng);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quite easy to add

```
var total = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < markerNodes.length; i++) {
   var name = markerNodes[i].getAttribute("name");
   var address = markerNodes[i].getAttribute("address");
   var amount = markerNodes[i].getAttribute("amount");

   total += parseFloat(amount);

   var distance = parseFloat(markerNodes[i].getAttribute("distance"));
   var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(
        parseFloat(markerNodes[i].getAttribute("lat")),
        parseFloat(markerNodes[i].getAttribute("lng")));
   createOption(name, distance, i);
   createMarker(latlng, name, address, total);
   bounds.extend(latlng);
}

console.log(total);
```

Comment: Only slight issue here is that it hasn't actually mathematically added the `amount` values together - just combined them in one giant numerical string.

Comment: Then see the comment behind the line, use `parseFloat(amount)` @michaelmcgurk

Comment: Edited it in the answer @michaelmcgurk

Comment: Many thanks for all your help @baao. My apologies for the unintended serious tone in my original reply - I forgot to add a `:-)` to it :-D

Comment: No problem, happy to help. @michaelmcgurk

Comment: Just wondering, instead of `console.log`, is it possible to display this on my page somewhere? Like as HTML? :-)

Comment: Sure, create an element e.g. with an id: `<span id="totalTarget"></span>` somewhere on your page, and replace console.log() with `document.getElementById("totalTarget").innerHTML = total;` @michaelmcgurk

Comment: You're a star - thank you so SO much, @baao - fantastic help :-)

Comment: Welcome again @michaelmcgurk

Answer (score 0):

This is another approach. (By using Array.reduce)

```
var total = Array.prototype.reduce.call(
   markerNodes, 
   (prev, cur) => prev + Number(cur.getAttribute("amount")), 
   0
);
```

Comment: true in isolation but this is redundant iteration in the case that you already have a for loop